# Editing plist file using shell script

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, plist, pkgbuild

I have used pkgbuild to create a default Component Property List file. The file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-     1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>BundleHasStrictIdentifier</key>
        <true/>
        <key>BundleIsRelocatable</key>
        <true/>
        <key>BundleIsVersionChecked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>BundleOverwriteAction</key>
        <string>upgrade</string>
        <key>RootRelativeBundlePath</key>
        <string>MyApp.app</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I want to modify this file by using shell script. I tried using **defaults write** but it didn't do anything.

What is the way to do it?(For example: I want to set BundleIsRelocatable to false)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Also:

```
plutil -replace BundleIsRelocatable -bool false plistfilename.plist
```

Answer (score 10):

For String use

```
plutil -replace NameOfProperty -string "yourNewValue" plistFileName.plist
```

Answer (score 6):

A bit late, but for the record, you just need to specify the absolute path AND add the *.plist* extension to the filename. If you are running your script in same directory that the plist file, your case would be translated into:

```
defaults write $PWD/YourPlistFilename.plist BundleIsRelocatable -bool false
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [PlistBuddy, a simple tutorial HERE.](http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2015/06/27/a-simple-plistbuddy-tutorial/)

```
 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :BundleIsRelocatable bool false" plistfilename.plist
```

It can run as ONE command line to update the key/value.
I use it to update `CFBundleVersion` generally, which can be found [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5310618/419348).

Answer (score 3):

Use [PlistBuddy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html)!

Very simple and straight forward.
Example:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ComponentPropertyList.plist
Command: Set :0:BundleIsRelocatable false
Command: save
Saving...
Command: exit
```

Thats it! Now BundleIsRelocatable is false :D

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i '' '/<key>BundleIsRelocatable</{n;s/true/false/;}' file.plist
```

If the plist is not XML, run `plutil -convert xml1 file.plist` first.

Answer (score 0):

The last response of Phil-CB [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5815759) should be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

cli for mac would be defaults read / write. example is we read the com.apple.dock.plist and change the dock orientation to the left.

1.) we read the keys and values needed or if you know this skip to 2.)

#let's you know and reads the available keys and values that can be changed.

```
defaults read com.apple.dock.plist
```

2.) #Let's modify the dock

## orientation is the key and left is the value

```
defaults write com.apple.dock orientation left
```

defaults help is very useful. Hope this helps This is the native way to do it in macOS without adding plistbuddy and you can just script it.